# rotating for loop in a cyclic process in java

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is my question: my `for` loop should rotate in cyclic process and the when it reaches to the value `7`, it should start form `1`.

and my `newcost` value should always be in increasing value.

here is my code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

public class PayCalculation {

    int cost,cost1=0;
    private String fromdate, todate, npersons, nrooms, rooms;
    long newcost;
    public String execute() throws Exception{

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(fromdate);   
        //Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(todate);   
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date1);
    //  c.setTime(date2);
        int dayOfWeek1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
       // int dayOfWeek2 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        Date past = dateFormat.parse(fromdate);
        Date today = dateFormat.parse(todate); 
        int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays(); 

        System.out.println(dayOfWeek1 + "  day of the week");

        System.out.println(days + " no of days");
        int i;
        for(i=0 ; i<=days ; i++){


            System.out.println(i);

            if(i==1 || i==7){

                System.out.println("sun or sat");
                cost1=1500;
            //  newcost=cost1;
            }
            if(i==2 || i==3 || i==4 || i== 5|| i==6){


                System.out.println(" other days");
                cost=1000;
        //  newcost=cost;
            }
            /*if(i==7){
                System.out.println("i==7");
                i=1;
            }
*/          newcost=0+cost+cost1;

            System.out.println(newcost+" new cost");

        }

        System.out.println(newcost);
        return "success";   

    }
```

Comment: Whats your question ?

Comment: So, did any of the below answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why `i==1` and `i==7` should refer to Sunday and Saturday because `days` is a number of days, and I don't see in your code where it is said that 1 is a Sunday. But anyway, assuming it's correct, you should do that :

```
for(i=1 ; i<=days ; i++){
    if(i==1 || (i>=7 && (i%8==0 || i%7==0))){
        System.out.println("sun or sat");
    }else{
        System.out.println(" other days");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it fits your needs though because I'm sorry to say that your question is a bit vague

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo math to get the day of week, like `int weekday = (i % 7) + 1` (plus some offset for the current day). To increase the `newCost` in each iteration, use `newcost += cost + cost1`.

However, this will increase `newCost` by `2500` in each week after the first, because you do not reset `cost` and `cost1` in the loop. Either add `cost = 0` and `cost1 = 0` to the top of your loop, or better, change your loop body to just `newCost += (weekday==1 || weekday==7) ? 1500 : 1000`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
    int weekday = ((dayOfWeek1 + i) % 7) + 1;
    newCost += (weekday == 1 || weekday == 7) ? 1500 : 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code had some mistakes, anyways you can put in another counter that keeps track of number of days (preventing infinite loop) and reset `i` at each occurence of `i=7` , the following code works :-

```
    int i;
    int dayscounter=days;
    for(i=0 ; i<=days && dayscounter>0 ; i++ ,dayscounter--){

   System.out.println(dayscounter+":"+i);
      if(i==2 || i==3 || i==4 || i== 5|| i==6){

            System.out.println(" other days");
            newcost+=1000;
        } 
        else if(i==1 || i==7){

            System.out.println("sun or sat");
            newcost+=1500;

            if(i==7){
                i=0; //reset i counter


            }

        }

        System.out.println(newcost+" new cost");

    }

    System.out.println(newcost);
```

Also note there is no need for cost and cost1 variables , you can directly increment `newcost` , because anyways in each iteration only one of the values `1000` or `1500` will be added to the `newcost`

Answer (score 0):

```
//mention this one in global level.


 List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

//mention all this in local level.
  String str_date = fromdate;
        String end_date = todate;

        System.out.println(fromdate+ "from date");
        System.out.println(todate + "to date ");

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        startDate = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
        endDate = (Date) formatter.parse(end_date);
        long interval = 24 * 1000 * 60 * 60;
        long endTime = endDate.getTime();
        long curTime = startDate.getTime();

     while (curTime <= endTime) {
            dates.add(new Date(curTime));
            curTime += interval;
        }

 //gettig this mon,tue,.... cost from database from the another class.

accost = crc.getAc(ac);/*this is the calling function to the other class to get  the   cost from mon  . . . . . sunday .*/
        mon = accost[0];
        tue = accost[1];
        wed = accost[2];
        thr = accost[3];
        fri = accost[4];
        sat = accost[5];
        sun = accost[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
            Date lDate = (Date) dates.get(i);
            // System.out.println(i);
            // System.out.println(dates.size());
            System.out.println(lDate);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(lDate);

            int dayOfWeek1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            System.out.println(dayOfWeek1 + " day of the week");

            int sundaycost = sun;
            int saturdaycost = sat;
            int moncost = mon;
            int tuecost = tue;
            int wedcost = wed;
            int thrcost = thr;
            int fricost = fri;

            if (dayOfWeek1 == 1) {

                cost = cost + sundaycost;
                System.out.println("weekend sunday");
                System.out.println(cost);

            }
            if (dayOfWeek1 == 7) {

                cost = cost + saturdaycost;
                System.out.println("weekend saturday");
                System.out.println(cost);
            }
            if (dayOfWeek1 == 2) {

                System.out.println("weekday monday");
                cost = cost + moncost;

            }
            if (dayOfWeek1 == 3) {

                System.out.println("weekday tuesday");
                cost = cost + tuecost;

            }
            if (dayOfWeek1 == 4) {

                System.out.println("weekday wednesday");
                cost = cost + wedcost;

            }
            if (dayOfWeek1 == 5) {

                System.out.println("weekday thrusday");
                cost = cost + thrcost;
            }
            if (dayOfWeek1 == 6) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("weekday friday");
                cost = cost + fricost;
            }
        }
```